# How to modify this Windows script to do a match?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

ffmpeg can resize a video/image file .. first is input_file .. parameters .. output_file ..

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf scale=320:240 output.avi
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i 20140724_071746.mp4 -vf scale=640:-1 20140724_071746_LOW_640.mp4
```

more info here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg

I want it to downscale all the videos on my microSD card to create space (I have originals backed-up)

So I want it to go throw all the files in all the sub-directories overnight and resize all the files. Chances are that the script might stop or crash and I would need to run it again, or if I add new files I would want to run it again.

So I would want it to skip processing all the files that have been processed AND their resized versions.

In my case if a `FILE_NAME.mp4` also has `FILE_NAME_LOW_640.mp4` SKIP it
AND
if a `FILE_NAME_LOW_640.mp4` has `*640` SKIP it

Here is my Windows batch script so far

```
REM @echo off
REM just save as "DOS"
REM cd /d C:\s

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%j in (*.mp4) do (
set filename=%%~nj
echo %%j

ffmpeg -i %%j -vf scale=640:-1 %%j_LOW_640.mp4

REM but now I want to add the two checks to skip files that have been resized .. or if they are the resized version 

REM if not "!filename!"=="%%j_LOW_640.mp4" AND IF FILE !COINTAIN *640* THEN ffmpeg -i %%j -vf scale=640:-1 %%j_LOW_640.mp4

)

pause
REM AND I would also want it to process all the sub-directories
```

In other words my questions for help are:

1. How can I do a check for a string if it contains a string match?
2. How can I have my script also process all the subdirectories?

Comment: Why don't you move both the source and resized file to another location after ffmpeg's done with it. You can recreate the directory structure of `c:\s` elsewhere by running `xcopy c:\s /t /e`

Comment: @RLH: Now and then I read similar statements from other people: _"This would be vastly easier to do in a VBScript"_, but they had never proved such assertions. I invite you to post the VBScript solution here, in a comment. Being "vastly easier" to do this in VBS, I assume it would be much shorter than the 8-lines Batch file solution [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908015/how-to-modify-this-windows-script-to-do-a-match/34911596#34911596), right?

Comment: It certainly cleaner. I show a vbs script walking the tree in my answer.

Comment: @RLH: This is funny! bgalea's vbs script is not just much larger than my Batch file solution (and not so clear, _in my opinion_), but it does _not_ solve the question either! It is reasonable to assume that the complete VBS solution would be _much larger_ than the Batch file one and not so clear for the very same reason... Given these "proves", it would be correct to say that "VBScript solutions are larger than Batch ones and, in certain cases, may be simpler to read and diagnose relative to what you use and know well", instead of "vastly easier"; don't you think?

Comment: Since this turned into an out of scope debate on language, i'll remove my comment(s) that was only originally intended to be an alternative solution and the OP didn't request info on it.  I apologize if my comment about vbs was out of place.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /s c:\somewhere\*.mp4') do (findstr /c:"_640" %A  || Echo ffeg etc %A)
```

`||` means run command if `findstr` returns an errorlevel of not 0, which it does if the string isn't found. `/s` in `dir` does subfolders.

Use `%%A` in batch and `%A` when typing.

See [Novice Batch Issue- Creating Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777412/novice-batch-issue-creating-files/34777779#34777779) for a list of command punctuation.

And a vbs script walking the tree. Run it with cscript in a command prompt(`cscript //nologo "c:\some path\script.vbs"`. Change starting folder for your machine (replace the `c:\users\david candy\documents`).

```
On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ProcessFolder "c:\users\david candy\documents"

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)

    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Set Fls = fldr.files

    For Each thing in Fls

        wscript.echo thing.name

    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders

    For Each thing in fldrs

        wscript.echo thing.name

        ProcessFolder thing.path

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the method be simple enough so it don't needs explanations. You may read further details on FOR parameter modifiers at `HELP FOR`

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B *.mp4') do (
   set "name=%%~Na"
   if "!name:~-3!" neq "640" if not exist "%%~DPNa_LOW_640.mp4" (
      ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf scale=640:-1 "%%~DPNa_LOW_640.mp4"
   )
)
```