# Copying to clipboard from .txt file via .bat file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, clipboard

I was following this [guide](http://www.yourtechtamer.com/blog/2011/08/can-you-create-a-shortcut-to-auto-paste-your-email-address-onto-the-clipboard/) but I cannot get it to function properly.
It's supposed to copy the text contained in ProgramTemplate.txt to the clipboard when you run the .bat file. Below is the .bat file code:

```
C:\\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k < c:\Users\Test user\Desktop\paste scripts\ProgramTemplate\ProgramTemplate.txt
c:\exit
```

Comment: You are missing the `CLIP` command in your code.  It shows it plain as day in the website you linked to.

Comment: I have clip in the file, forgot to type it into this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@bgalea's answer is correct, you should use clip in your command.

However, please note that you should put double quotes around the filename, as your script will otherwise break if the filename contains spaces.

Also not that you can also use input `<` in your code, which instead of piping output from another command, immediately puts the contents into a command. To conclude, the following codes will both work:

```
@echo off
clip < "c:\Users\Test user\Desktop\paste scripts\ProgramTemplate\ProgramTemplate.txt"
```

or

```
@echo off
type "c:\Users\Test user\Desktop\paste scripts\ProgramTemplate\ProgramTemplate.txt" | clip
```

Answer (score 9):

```
type file.txt | clip
```

See `type /?` and `clip /?` for help.

See [Novice Batch Issue- Creating Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777412/novice-batch-issue-creating-files/34777779#34777779) for a list of command prompt punctuation.

Comment: You should put double-quotes around the filename, as I explain in my answer.